# Get Username & Id From Comments inside Facebook Page Through Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I had tried the graph api comment function to access comments from a page post. However, the data that I obtained is only comments text without the details of user such as username & id. If I want to get such information, is there anything I have to do?

Comment: Likely this requires your app to be in live mode. While in dev mode, test with a comment made by a user that has a role in the app.

Comment: That mean I can only access to those information till i switch to live mode? In order to do that, my app shall went through FB reviewed?

Comment: Yes, you will need to have all permissions and features that require review to be approved, otherwise you will lose access.

Comment: One more thing to confirm, if i got all the permission, can I access to all page comment details or only the page that I owned?

Comment: I don’t know; but you would have to get your app reviewed for the Page Public Content Access feature in the first place, before you can access _any_ data of pages you don’t have admin access to.